# Adding values to a multi-index dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

df

[image: dataframe df]

dataframe df

and df2

| match ID | gender | winner | team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1023 | male | Australia | Australia |
| 1023 | male | Australia | Scotland |
| 4585 | male | Hong Kong | New Zealand |
| 4585 | male | Hong Kong | Hong Kong |
| 2099 | female | Pakistan | Pakistan |
| 2099 | female | Pakistan | Australia |

df2 is a dataframe of match records, there is a row for each team that has played a match (there are two records for each match ID). For example, row one and two is for the same match between Australia and Scotland.

I am trying to iterate through df2 where for a particular row in df2, if the `winner` and `team` column match we can add 1 to the appropriate space in the `wins` column in df and if they are different then we can add 1 to the appropriate space in the `loss` column in df.

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    if row["winner"] == row['team']:
        df.at[df.loc[row["team"], row["gender"]], 'wins', df.loc[row["teams"], row["gender"]]["wins"]+1]
    else:
        df.at[df.loc[row["team"], row["gender"]], 'loss', df.loc[row["teams"], row["gender"]]["loss"]+1]
```

Resulting in the following error: `TypeError: _get_value() got multiple values for argument 'takeable'`. I tried testing out changing one value in df but I either get errors or the entire dataframe changes to the specified value.

Comment: kindly provide reproducible dataframes, with expected output dataframe

Answer (score 1):

In order to access the row from multiindex you can specify the indexes like df.loc[ind1, ind2, ...]. You can simply do it like this:

```
if row["winner"] == row["team"]:
        df.loc[row["team"], row["gender"]]["wins"] += 1
    else:
        df.loc[row["team"], row["gender"]]["loss"] += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out rows with same `winner` and `team`, so possible reshape by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) for count values:

```
df = (df2[df2['winner'].ne(df2['team'])]
          .rename(columns={'team':'loss', 'winner':'wins'})
          .melt(id_vars='gender',value_vars=['wins','loss'], value_name='country')
          .pivot_table(index=['country','gender'],
                       columns='variable',
                       aggfunc='size',
                       fill_value=0)
          .assign(total=lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
          )
print (df)
variable            loss  wins  total
country     gender                   
Australia   female     1     0      1
            male       0     1      1
Hong Kong   male       0     1      1
New Zealand male       1     0      1
Pakistan    female     0     1      1
Scotland    male       1     0      1
```

Last use [`DataFrame.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add counts with set original order in `df1`:

```
out = df1.add(df, fill_value=0).astype(int).reindex(index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)
print (out)
                    wins  loss  total
country     gender                   
Australia   male       1     0      1
            female     0     1      1
Pakistan    male       0     0      0
            female     1     0      1
New Zealand male       0     1      1
            female     0     0      0
Scotland    male       0     1      1
            female     0     0      0
Hong Kong   male       1     0      1
            female     0     0      0
Zimbabwe    male       0     0      0
            female     0     0      0
```